# How can I get a URL from a selected hyperlink using Applescript?

Tags: applescript

I’m attempting to create an Applescript that will grab the URL from a selected hyperlink.

For some backstory: the system that my company has in place doesn’t play well with generating reports, so I created a script into which I can paste a list of URLs, at which point Safari will go through each page and select all the data, copy it, and parse out what I need.

However, each page that I’m parsing has a link on it that says, for example, “Edit”. If I post it into, say, Pages, the hyperlink is preserved. It would GREATLY speed up my flow if I could somehow get the URL contained in that hyperlink.

Any ideas?

Comment: If all you need is to extract specific elements from a URL, I recommend a web-scraping utility such as [xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html), which can download a given URL's page and extract elements from it using, e.g., [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xpath).

Answer (score 0):

Drew, I suspect you got no answer because it's a little difficult to discern what you're wanting. But, here is a script that will grab the raw text of a web page, and then find the first href hyperlink that is named "Edit", and then return the target URL that it's linking to. It uses CURL to pull the content and offset to find the link name. You might have to adjust the tag identifiers surrounding the Link Name you're searching for.

```
property baseURL : "http://www.mycoolsite.index.html"
property linkName : "Here"

set rawHTML to do shell script "curl '" & baseURL & "'"
set theOffset to offset of ("\">" & linkName & "</a>") in rawHTML
set rawHTML to text 1 thru (theOffset - 1) of rawHTML
set otid to AppleScript's text item delimiters
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "http://"
set targetURL to (text item -1 of (text items of rawHTML))
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to otid
return targetURL
```